# admin_post action not usable if admin access denied to user

Tags: wp-admin, forms, user-access

Right now users with a certain role would be redirected away with a hook into `admin_init` depending on the following conditional

```
if (is_admin() && in_array($role_id, $user->roles))
```

However, this prevents the logged in user with that role to use the `admin_post` action hook. So is there a way to redirect only admin dashboard access or functions?

I've looked around for the best option to handle WordPress form submission  and read that `admin_post` is the hook to use, but now it seems that I can't use this now if the role is being redirected when accessing `wp_admin/admin-post.php`?

Answer (score 1):

What about (1) `current_screen`? action hook, or a condition for (2)
 [`get_current_screen()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/) in your conditional and then calling `wp_redirect`?

Both give you a [`WP_Screen object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen) which has several parameters, including a [`$parent_base` property](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen#Public_Properties) that can give broader inclusion if needed, too.

Here's the property list from the codex:

> **$action** Any action associated with the screen. 'add' for *-add.php and
>   *-new.php screens. Empty otherwise.
>
> **$base** The base type of the screen. This is typically the same as $id but with any post types and
>   taxonomies stripped. For example, for an $id of 'edit-post' the base
>   is 'edit'.
>
> **$id** The unique ID of the screen.
>
> **$is_network** Whether the
>   screen is in the network admin.
>
> **$is_user** Whether the screen is in the
>   user admin.
>
> **$parent_base** The base menu parent. This is derived from
>   $parent_file by removing the query string and any .php extension.
>   $parent_file values of 'edit.php?post_type=page' and
>   'edit.php?post_type=post' have a $parent_base of 'edit'.
>
> **$parent_file**
>   The $parent_file for the screen per the admin menu system. Some
>   $parent_file values are 'edit.php?post_type=page', 'edit.php', and
>   'options-general.php'.
>
> **$post_type** The post type associated with the
>   screen, if any. The 'edit.php?post_type=page' screen has a post type
>   of 'page'. The 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=$taxonomy&post_type=page'
>   screen has a post type of 'page'.
>
> **$taxonomy** The taxonomy associated
>   with the screen, if any. The 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category' screen
>   has a taxonomy of 'category'.

Just a quick example of possible usage, not working code as is:

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'my_function' );

function my_function( $current_screen ) {
     //true for anything other than page prefixed with edit.php
     if ( $current_screen->parent_base !== 'edit' ) { 
          //get user role here, then:
          if ( in_array( $user->roles ) ) {
             //send to /wp-admin/ 
            //note: for multisite I don't think admin_url() is the function you need
              wp_redirect( admin_url() ); 
          }
     }
 }
```

There may be a better approach for your specific case, but in general I've used something similar open/close access to a post_type or user profile screen without affecting ability for users to log in.